# How do I enable one specific extension with all other extensions disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

An expected output of a certain extension stopped occurring, so I want to figure out if there is some interference. I used the `Reload With Extensions Disabled` command to try running the extension in isolation, but apparently I am unable to enable any extensions whatsoever in this mode, which kind of makes sense, but is unintuitive.

How can I achieve the desired effect of running with all but a select few of my extensions disabled?

[image]

Comment: If the UI greys out the control to it, I'm guessing that means it's by design that you can't enable extensions in that mode. Would you accept an answer that just says "manually disable all but the extension you want to debug"?

Comment: @user If so, then I should rephrase my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Note: To use `Profiles` you must currently have the setting `Workbench > Experimental > Settings Profiles: Enabled checked` (I believe in vscode v1.75 they will be enabled by default, or st least the `experimental` designation will be removed).

Create a temporary profile: Gear icon/Profiles/Create.../Create a Temporary Profile.

That will reload with all extensions disabled, but you can then quickly install the one particular extension you want to test into that temporary profile.

Then when you are done you can go back to your `Default` profile the same way (with all your previous extensions enabled) and the temporary profile will be deleted.

Comment: I can't seem to find such menu option in the side bar. What I see there in the gear icon menu is only settings, extensions, shortcuts, snippets, theme, sync, updates. Not even bringing up the command palette gives me any such option when searching. Can you provide some screenshots or links to external guides?

Comment: Sorry, I remember that you have to have the setting `Workbench > Experimental > Settings Profiles: Enabled` checked for it to work in Stable - although I thinkwith the next release the `experimental` tag comes off.

Comment: Oh this is amazing! Thanks! Just one thing, creating new profile results in blank profile without any extensions even **installed** not just disabled, but installing the one required is still easy. Also, it is possible to import another profile into it. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated that you want to do this for troubleshooting purposes, here's an approach without much persistent setup / teardown (compared to the other answer suggesting usage of [the Profiles feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)).

You can use the `code --list-extensions` and the `--disable-extension <ext-id>` extensions together.

> `--disable-extension <ext-id>`: Disable the provided extension. This option is not persisted and is effective only when the command opens a new window.

So either you could write it all out manually (using VS Code itself with its multicursor editing / column (box) selection would help), or I imagine one could do something like this (example that starts VS Code with all extensions disabled except the cSpell extension):

```
code $(code --list-extensions | grep -v 'streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker' | xargs -I % echo '--disable-extension %')
```

If you want to ignore multiple extensions, switch to grep's regex mode and use the `|` operator, or pipe through multiple `grep -v` commands.

Comment: Incredible. This is something I will definitely keep in mind!